# Typo3 solr auto-suggest throwing exception on facet.field: spell

Tags: solr, typo3

While using auto-suggest feature with typo3 solr extension I am getting following exceptions from solr.

RequestHandlerBase
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Exception during facet.field: spell

HttpSolrCall
null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Exception during facet.field: spell

Does anyone have an idea on what will be the reason for this exception? I am using solr version:6.2.1. I have tried to clear solr core and re-indexed the contents, then for few hours it worked very well but after that the exception appeared again and auto-suggest returned null values. Is it an issue with my content or solr configuration? Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see in https://github.com/TYPO3-Solr/ext-solr/issues/1286 
That should be fixed in EXT:Solr v. 9+ https://github.com/TYPO3-Solr/ext-solr/pull/2413
You could use XCLass solution from Andreas and Marcus.

Comment: Hi Rafael Kähm, Thanks for your support, its worked :). I have used the Xclass mentioned here (https://github.com/TYPO3-Solr/ext-solr/issues/1286#issuecomment-531689627)